# Graphicsmagick autoOrient().size() gives the flipped image size in node.js library

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

How can I get the image size after the image has been autooriented?

The size still gives the pre-auto-oriented size rather than the one after it's been rotated. (so the x and y dimensions are flipped).

```
var original = gm(response.Body).autoOrient();

        original.size(function (err, size) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }

            resize_photo(size, max_size, original, function (err, photo) {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
                res.send(photo);
            });
        });
```

Comment: I don't know `node.js` but my guess would be that you need to do a `+repage()` to re-sync things after the `autoOrient()` but before the `size()`... http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-repage

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to write to a buffer and then call `.size` like this:

```
gm(response.Body).autoOrient().toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
  if (!err) {
    gm(buffer).size(function (err, size) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(size);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**Note:** This works because `.size` runs the image magick command `identify` on the new auto oriented buffer and not the original file or the original buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found that if I write the autoOrient file out then read it back in, size() reads the flipped dimensions.

```
//Ignoring errors   
 gm('/images/original.jpg').autoOrient().write('/images/autoOriented.jpg', function (err) {
    gm('/images/autoOriented.jpg').size(function(err, size) {
        console.log('size: ', size);
    });
});
```

Comment: seems like it would be a bit expensive to write to disk and then read it back in again.